# How to call C++ functions from Python code in linux?

Tags: c++, python, include

I want to call functions of a C++ program from Python code.

How can make C++ functions available in a Python program?

Comment: See examples and more discussion here [Calling C/C++ from python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/

Boost.Python, a C++ library which enables seamless interoperability between C++ and the Python programming language.

Comment: tanks  guys for answer this question

Answer (score 1):

You can find a simple example of Python's native C API (works just as well for C++) [here](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html)

If you deal with numerical calculations and you use numpy in your python code, you should consider numpy's extensive additions to the C API ([manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.html))